# "Illegal start of simple expression" inside function definition

Tags: scala

I have no experience with Scala at all. I have been given some code examples of Scala to see if I can understand what the code is doing and perhaps suggest ways to improve it (fat chance). Albeit I can see that some lists, random numbers, and case statements are within the code.

I tried to run this through an online Scala interface, I keep getting the error "Illegal start of simple expression"
Could any of you nice Scala people eyeball this code and perhaps give me a heads up.

Tried running this code in Scastie Online

```
import scala.util.Random

object ScalaApp {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   sayHello
   val randomList: List[Long] = generateList(20)
   printMaximumNumber(randomList)
   printMinimumNumber(randomList)
   println(Average(randomList))
 }

 private def sayHello: Unit = {
   Random.nextInt(5) match {
     case 0 => println("Hello, World!")
     case 1 => println("Hi!")
     case 2 => println("Good morning!")
     case 3 => println("Bye!")
     case 4 => println("Hello?")
     }
 }

 def tellAJoke(): Unit = {
   println("I, for one, like Roman numerals")
 }

 def generateList(n: Int): List[Int] = {
   Seq.fill(n)(Random.nextInt).toList
 }

 private def printMaximumNumber(randomList: List[Int]): Unit = {
   randomList.max
 }

 def printMinimumNumber(randomList: List[Int], acc: Option[Int] = None, i: Int = 0): Unit = {
   if (i < randomList.size)
     val temporaryMinimum = acc
     if (!acc.isDefined || randomList(i) < acc.get)
       temporaryMinimum = randomList(i)
     printMinimumNumber(randomList, Some(temporaryMinimum), i + 1)
   else
     println(s"Minimum: ${acc.getOrElse("???")}")
 }

 def Average(randomList: List[Int]): Int = {`enter code here`
   randomList.foldLeft(0)(_ + _) / randomList.size
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to compile by making the following changes.

```
val randomList: List[Int] = generateList(20)  //not List[Long]
```

...and...

```
def printMinimumNumber(randomList: List[Int], acc: Option[Int] = None, i: Int = 0): Unit = {
  if (!acc.isDefined || randomList(i) < acc.get)
    printMinimumNumber(randomList, Some(randomList(i)), i + 1)
  else
    println(s"Minimum: ${acc.getOrElse("???")}")
}
```

...and...

```
def Average(randomList: List[Int]): Int = {//`enter code here` (commented out)
```

No guarantees that it runs or does anything useful, but it compiles.

Comment: Hi jwvh, thanks for taking the time to look at this for me.  :)

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. ```
   val randomList: List[Long] = generateList(20)
   ```

   You define this as a `List[Long]`, and then call a bunch of functions which require a `List[Int]`. These aren't interchangeable; change this to `val randomList: List[Int] = ....`.
2. ```
   def printMinimumNumber(randomList: List[Int], acc: Option[Int] = None, i: Int = 0): Unit = {
      if (i < randomList.size)
        val temporaryMinimum = acc
        if (!acc.isDefined || randomList(i) < acc.get)
          temporaryMinimum = randomList(i)
        printMinimumNumber(randomList, Some(temporaryMinimum), i + 1)
      else
        println(s"Minimum: ${acc.getOrElse("???")}")
    }
   ```

   While you can sometimes get away with not using curly braces (e.g. simple, single-line expressions) you can't just avoid them completely. You need curly braces around the outer if/else: `if (i < randomList.size) { ... } else { ... }`.

   Also, you can't re-assign a `val` (which you're doing with `temporaryMinimum`). Use `var` if you want to assign the same variable to different values. Also, `acc` is an `Option[Int]`, not an `Int`, so you'll need to do something like `acc.getOrElse(0)` if you want to assign `temporaryMinimum` at the start of this function. This function in general is already super ugly, but at least it'll compile.
3. ```
   def Average(randomList: List[Int]): Int = {`enter code here`
      randomList.foldLeft(0)(_ + _) / randomList.size
   }
   ```

   Get rid of the `enter code here` part. Not sure why that's there.

[Et voilà, it compiles!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/fvpFxYU/0) This is some of the most bodged together code I've seen in a while, but it prints *something* now at least.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for taking the time to look over the code and thanks for the feedback. As I said I am not a Scala user. :)